# Add one key to each dict inside a dict, doing this in one line

Tags: python

I have a dict, the structure is like the following

```
{'kelly': {'w1': 8, 'w2': 12},
 'elisa': {'w1': 2, 'w2': 0},
 'julia': {'w1': 4, 'w2': 6}}
```

I would have this results to

```
{'kelly': {'w1': 8, 'w2': 12, 'total': 20},
 'elisa': {'w1': 2, 'w2': 0, 'total': 2},
 'julia': {'w1': 4, 'w2': 6, 'total': 10}}
```

This is what I did

```
def append_summation_field(data):
    for k, v in data.items():
        v['total'] = sum(v.values())
    return data
```

My question is, can I do this in one line code like list-comprehension or lambda or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {'kelly': {'w1': 8, 'w2': 12},
        'elisa': {'w1': 2, 'w2': 0},
        'julia': {'w1': 4, 'w2': 6}}

print({k: {**v, "total": sum(v.values())} for k, v in data.items()})
```

---

```
{'kelly': {'w1': 8, 'w2': 12, 'total': 20}, 'elisa': {'w1': 2, 'w2': 0, 'total': 2}, 'julia': {'w1': 4, 'w2': 6, 'total': 10}}
```

Comment: I think you can do `"total": sum(v.values())` without the extra `dict` nesting (like this: `{**v, "total": sum(v.values())}`).

Answer (score 3):

Under [PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#specification) of Python 3.9, using the `dict` update operator, you will also be able to do:

```
{k: v | {"total": sum(v.values())} for k, v in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions would be complicated as the result should be a dict (you'd have to unpack it and repack it a dict). But you can use a for-loop on one line:

```
for k in d.keys(): d[k]['total']=sum(d[k].values())
```